# Links to AJAX calls do not work

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, cross-browser

Hi all i am writing a Rails application and i include some link_to_remote links
The generated code is

```
<a href="#" onclick="new Ajax.Request('/b10/categories/games?category=Action', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true}); return false;">Test</a>
```

That works perfectly fine on Safari and Firefox but when i try to click the link on IE7 and Opera it does not even hit the server.

Any hints ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad practice to include all of this code in the `<a href>` tag anyways. I suggest you make a function such as:

```
function doAjax(url)
{
   new Ajax.Request(url, {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true});
   return false;
}
```

in the javascript code. And change the url to say instead:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return doAjax('/b10/categories/games?category=Action');">
Test</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a fully qualified URL: `http://.....`